# Why CORS headers does not concern http requests from the browser

Tags: django, http, web, cors

I want to understand in depth CORS.

If we consider the definition of https://developer.mozilla.org/:

Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) is an HTTP-header based mechanism that allows a server to indicate any origins (domain, scheme, or port) other than its own from which a browser should permit loading resources.

**So my question is quite simple :**

Its normal if CORS policy is triggered if we use fetch() from a website hosted on a separate server (separate ip). But the question is, why when we make a HTTP request from a browser to a particular website the CORS policy is not triggered ,knowing that the source of the request comes from a different ip from that of the server hosting the website ?

*Thanks in advance*

Comment: "when we make a HTTP request from a browser to a particular website". How do you send those HTTP requests? By navigating the site normally?

Comment: @jub0bs "By navigating the site normally ?" . Yes exactly.

Comment: CORS only applies to scripts (fetch, XHR, EventSource, etc.), not to normal navigation.